# MS Active Directory users group membership through nested ldap group

Tags: active-directory, ldap, artifactory, group, memberof

We have a up to date ArtifactoryPro deployed on-premise with MS Active Directory connected. Everything works out if user of synced groups have direct membership of these groups.

Our problem as example:

`UserX` belongs to `Group-ORG-X`

`Group-ORG-X` is a member of `Group-Artifactory-X-RW`; `Group-Artifactory-X-RW` is synced in Artifactory and used in permission targets. But RT does not find `UserX` as memberOf->memberOf that group.

```
UserX -> Group-ORG-X -> Group-Artifactory-X-RW
```

Is this even possible or would this be feature request? We have similar setups working in confluence/jira/keycloak

Group search is set to dynamic. We also tried static and hierarchical. We tried to import all groups as well.

Comment: If you set the "force_attribute_search": true, for this group does it work (default value is false)?
With this REST API:
https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/add-ldap-group-settings

Comment: Thank you for this idea.. didn't know this attribute exists, since there is no option for this in the ui, but no, this didn't work out.